# Simulating RISCV on RHEL5 -- Missing libmpc-devel

Tags: rhel, riscv

My goal is to simulate RISCV in VCS on RHEL 5.11.

I am following the lowRISC tagged memory tutorial, environment setup guide:
http://www.lowrisc.org/docs/tagged-memory-v0.1/setup/

The apt-get commands are substituted with yum and equivalent packages, per the GNU toolchain repo readme:
https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain

```
sudo yum install autoconf automake libmpc-devel mpfr-devel gmp-devel gawk  bison flex texinfo patchutils gcc gcc-c++
```

The `libmpc-devel` package cannot be found, and I cannot build GCC for RISCV without it.

I believe this package can be found for RHEL6, but I do not have VCS available on a RHEL6 machine.

Is there a workaround for this issue -- e.g. can I build GCC for RISCV on another machine, then do compilation and simulation on different boxes?